# Windows XP - CHKDSK runs on every boot

Tags: windows-xp, chkdsk

Since 6th October I'm facing CHKDSK at boot problem on Windows XP SP3 machine.

At every CHKDSK I get this message at log:

```
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
Usn Journal verification completed.
Windows has checked the file system and found no problems.
....
....
0 KB in bad sectors.
```

Also, the defrag tool from Admin Account doesn't work, as it says to run `chkdsk /f`

How do I prevent from running CHKDSK on every boot?

Comment: Do as Dave M suggests, back up data now Then run seatools.

Comment: Sure. May I ask, when no errors thrown (bad sectors) then why this CHKDSK appears at BOOT time? Thanks

Comment: See this MS KB article: [Chkdsk.exe or Autochk.exe starts when you try to shut down or restart your computer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831426)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back up the data now before something happens.  Assuming this is a Seagate drive, SEATOOLS would be a good thing to try.  Vendor tools will often find issues that SMART will not.

Comment: Yeah, taking backup now. This is happening since 6th, and never happened. No Errors thrown. After data backup, first should I try to DEL the partition and create it again?

Comment: in a command prompt use  >chkntfs C: to observe if the dirty bit itself is set,  and  >chkdsk.exe C: /f to do the "deeper" scanning.  I think that the chkdsk that occurs at startup (when needed) is the lightweight setting of it, and does not always "fix" everything.  a Common way to fix this was to do the next level up of chkdsk with the F parameter.  I Comment here because as dave pointed out at any rate a person would want to backup thier data anyways. Lots of people "fixed" this with a full chkdsk, doesnt mean it will fix it for you though.

Comment: I've SOLVED this problem. First, I took ~20 GB data backup to other drives. Then did a quick check in the Registry for autocheck autochk * entries. Nothing unusual I've found. So before installing SeaTools, I want to test my own trick. DELETED the 25 GB NTFS D: partition. Created it again. Reboot the PC. Voila, no more CHKDSK!! I'm happy and relieved. Thanks all for the tricks. No CHKDSK entries found in Event logger (Winlogon entry).